# Different func parameters at the same time

Tags: swift, function, dictionary, parameters, logic

To learn about `dictionaries` I am trying to use a single `function` with `arguments` for different operations.

This function is actually the logic of five similar functions that were independently called by five individual cells at the time to do stuff like calculating a difference. Not very optimized I thought.

Here is the logic now, calling the function with different `parameters` at the same time:

```
let milkUSD : Double = 3.00
let chocolateUSD : Double = 4.50
let reduction1 : Double = 0.50
let reduction2 : Double = 0.30

var prices : [String : Double] = ["p1": milkUSD, "p2": chocolateUSD]
var reductions : [String : Double] = ["r1": reduction1, "r2": reduction2]

func calculateReduction(_ price: String, _ reduction: String) {
    let price = prices[price]
    guard price != nil else { return }
    let reduction = reductions[reduction]
    guard reduction != nil else { return }

    let result = price! - reduction!
    print(result)
}

//called at the same time:
calculateReduction("p1", "r1") //prints 2.5
calculateReduction("p2", "r2") //prints 4.2
```

It works in the playground but will using a function like this cause me problems in my app when it will be called at the same time to process more complex operations and with value changing variables? Or do I simply underestimate computers haha?

Comment: I do not understand what is the exact problem? Please provide the problem, miscalculation :) You are guarding the price twice, there should be 
`guard reduction != nil else { return }`

Comment: There is no problem yet but I'm affraid of one later haha! So my question is: Will this function work when called with different parameters at the same time inside my app?

Comment: I guess it should work, since you are not changing the values of the dictionary. I do not see any other problem. For guards I would suggest to use.
`guard let r = reduction else { return }` later use `r` instead of `reduction!`. The same applies for `price!`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shalva, in my app I **will** be changing the values of the variables inside the dictionaries, is that a problem? Some of them are `userDefaults` keys

Comment: If you change the values of dictionary you will get incorrect values for the next calls. Imagine you will make the reduction several times  :)